# Two Background images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add two backgrounds in CSS but one image to fill the entire background and the other to be aligned on the centre right of the page. Here is a section of my current StyleSheet:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: #384047;
  background-image: url(http://footyprofit.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/golf-background.jpg);
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

I've tried separating the URLs with a comma and then separating the positioning by comma but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You may follow CSS3.info or CSS-tricks as they have clearly explained. You may follow http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ or https://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/ You can also follow MDN link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds

Answer (score 2):

Set the height of the parent element to 100% i.e. to html. Then used the `cover` value of `background-size` to occupy full space of the underlying image. Set `right center` to the 'background-position' of the first image.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/300x300/333"), url("http://placehold.it/1200x1200");
  background-position: right center, center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto auto, cover;
  color: #384047;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 supports multiple background images;

```
    body {
      font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
      color: #384047;
      background-image: url(http://footyprofit.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/golf-background.jpg), url(http://footyprofit.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/golf-background.jpg);
      background-position: center center, left top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
    }
```

refer http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Answer (score 0):

You can see this tutorial : http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

> ## example1 {
>
> width: 500px;
>
> height: 250px;
>
> background-image: url(sheep.png), url(betweengrassandsky.png);
>
> background-position: center bottom, left top;
>
> background-repeat: no-repeat;
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Refer this.it will help you...

```
 body {
background-image: url(http://footyprofit.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/golf-background.jpg), url(http://footyprofit.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/golf-background.jpg);
background-position: center right, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
padding: 15px;
 }
```